# off canvas menu doesn't push content away

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, menu

So i have this off canvas menu which ALMOST works, but not quite!
The menu pushes in from the right, but the rest of the site is not pushed to the left. I'm quite sure that I'm missing something in the CSS, i.e. the class I'm toggling (.toggleNav)!
Can't figure it out though, need your help! Thanks a lot!!

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 
 $('#toggleMenu').click(function() {
 $('#siteWrapper').toggleClass('toggleNav');
 });
 
});
```

```css
* {padding:0;margin:0;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:normal}
body, html {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
ul {list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

#siteWrapper{
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 background: lightgrey; 
}
#canvasWrapper {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0;
 right:-400px;
 width: 400px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #3186CD; 
}
#siteWrapper, #canvasWrapper {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform: translateX(0);
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
 transition: .3s ease all;
}
#siteWrapper.toggleNav #canvasWrapper { /* quite possibly wrong... */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
 transform: translateX(-400px); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="siteWrapper">
    <h1>Off Canvas Menu</h1><br>
    <h3>This should slide to the left! Some more text to have something left on the canvas...</h3><br>


 <div id="canvasWrapper" >
     <div id="menu">
         <ul>
             <li>home</li>
                <li>infos</li>
                <li>something</li>
                <li>contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="toggleMenu">toggle Menu</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with an additional wrapper it worked:

```js
function toggleNav() {
$('#siteWrapper').toggleClass('showNav');
}

$(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    toggleNav(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {float:right;margin-right:30%;cursor:pointer;}

#siteWrapper {
 position: relative;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: lightgrey; 
}
#siteCanvas {
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
 transform: translateX(0);
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
 transition: .3s ease all;
 padding: 5% 0;
}
#siteMenu {
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: -300px;
 background: black;
 color: white;
 border-left: 1px solid white;
 z-index: 5000;
 padding-top: 5%;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
#siteWrapper.showNav #siteCanvas {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
 transform: translateX(-300px); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="siteWrapper">
<div id="siteCanvas">
<div id="siteMenu">
  <nav>MENU
  <ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>away</li>
    <li>tickets</li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

  <button class="toggle" type="button">toggle</button>
<h1>the</h1>
  <h3>actual</h3>
  <p>site with some lorem ipsum to show the push effect</p>
    
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#siteWrapper.toggleNav { /* quite possibly wrong... */
-webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
transform: translateX(-400px);  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i've tried this before, it makes the menu move 800px to the left instead of 400px... i'm assuming it's the sum of 400px from the #siteWrapper plus 400px from the #canvasWrapper?

Comment: Ok then apply the css only on .toggleNav so if it moves 400px to left the offcanvas will be shown.

Comment: now only the grey canvas moves to the left, but the off canvas menu doesn't move in...

Comment: Why not try to make it -200px for both off canvas and siteWrapper.

Comment: like this:
#siteWrapper.toggleNav #canvasWrapper, #siteWrapper.toggleNav {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
 transform: translateX(-200px); 
}
now the menu (#canvasWrapper) is only 200px wide..

Comment: I think i should copy the code and try it myself to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is really the solution.
      #siteWrapper.toggleNav , #siteWrapper.toggleNav #canvasWrapper{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400px);
    transform: translateX(-400px);}
    #siteWrapper.toggleNav #canvasWrapper{
     Right:-400px;
    }

Comment: this gives me an extra 400px between the right end and the menu, e.g. in a 900px viewport:
[                        900px viewport                  ]
[canvas 100px] [menu 400px] [extra 400px]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, i copied it and fixed - i mean i did what i can-

```
* {padding:0;margin:0;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight:normal}
body, html {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
ul {list-style:none;padding-left:10px;}

#siteWrapper{
overflow:shown;
position:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 40%;
background: lightgrey;  
}
#canvasWrapper {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
right:-400px;
width: 400px;
height: 100%;
display:none;
background: #3186CD;    
}
#siteWrapper, #canvasWrapper {
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
-webkit-transition: .3s ease all;
transition: .3s ease all;
}
 #siteWrapper.toggleNav {
left:-400px;
overflow:;
}
#siteWrapper.toggleNav #canvasWrapper{
right:-400px;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: nope, not working, canvas moves, but not the menu. are you actually testing this?

Comment: I really tested it and it worked on firefox, chrome and IE. It really worked for me